# Spring Thymeleaf shortening url (form - get) parameters

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Current state :

https://localhost:8443/workaround/?query=dasda&atn=s&filterSoftwareType=ANY.....

Desired state :
https://localhost:8443/workaround/?**q**=dasda&atn=s&**fst**=ANY.....

**Shorten url by using q instead of query and fst instead of filterSoftwareType**

**My thymeleaf html** looks like this, short sample :

```
<form action="#" class="card card-sm rounded"
                  method="get"
                  th:action="@{${T(com.bisciak.workaround.util.Utils).MAPPING_INDEX}}" th:object="${search}">

     <div class="col">
           <input class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-borderless"
                               placeholder="Search here"
                               style="padding-left: 1rem"
                               th:field="${search.query}" type="search"/>
     </div> etc...
```

**Controller** :

```
  @GetMapping(value = Utils.MAPPING_INDEX, params = "atn=s")
 public ModelAndView indexActionSearch(@ModelAttribute(name = "s") Optional<Search> search .....
```

Search object has properties like query etc, bud I dont want to rename those for sure! It would be just horrible naming thruought the code I only want to use short versions for URL.

**Anyone has idea how to do this? I have tried name attribute on input bud that didnt helped :/.**

I also want to keep stuff in the form so url is automatically build.
I also want to keep this as get and not a post so user can share easily this link via copy paste etc from URL bar. With post he would not see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `th:field` attribute is to easily build a form from a Java object, and for the fields to post back using same names so the values can be auto-assigned back into a Java object, of the same type, on the server.

If you want different names, then you're not using it for it's intended purpose, so stop using it.

If you look at the documentation, i.e. chapter [7.2 Inputs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#inputs), you see what `th:fields` does:

> Let’s see now how to add an input to our form:
>
> ```html
> <input type="text" th:field="*{datePlanted}" />
> ```
>
> ... In this case (`input[type=text]`), the above line of code is similar to:
>
> ```html
> <input type="text" id="datePlanted" name="datePlanted" th:value="*{datePlanted}" />
> ```

So, change your code to do this:

```html
<form ... th:object="${search}">

    <input ... name="q" th:value="*{query}"/>
```

Whether you also need `id="q"` is up to you.

Note that if you use `th:value="${search.query}"`, then there is no need for `th:object="${search}"`

Comment: Damn it works exactly as you said.  Thanks this solves my problem !